# QML Canvas/Context2D fillText() unexpected behaviour

Tags: qt, canvas, qml

I am trying to code a text editor from scratch in C++ using Qt/QML. For drawing the text I use a `Canvas` with a `Context2D` , which looks roughly like this:

```
function drawString(text, x, y, font) {
    var ctx = getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(qsTr(text), x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

In order to graphically represent a selected area, I want to invert the selecion, for instance place a black rectangle over an area and make the text white.

For this I will use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor"`

So the problem I ran into is: when I draw a text with the function above in black, and then afterwards paint the same text in the same location in white I would expect this canvas to be white again. Instead there is still some kind of outline of the text visible (like there is a shadow).

I already tried switching off all shadow parameters but it didn't solve my problem.

Here is a screenshot so you get a better idea of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Consider posting the full code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the problem myself. The `antialiasing` property was set to `true`, which caused the effect. By setting it to `false` the text doesn't look as pretty but the shadow is gone.

Comment: Did you try to clear the canvas before repainting? (try `ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height)`).